# Unable to parse english sentences using engmalt of maltparser

Tags: python, parsing, nltk

I have installed maltparser-1.7.2 from here in drive 'C' of my computer by the name maltparser and set a enviroment variable:

```
name=MALTPARSERHOME
value=C:\maltparser
```

I changed the maltparser-1.7.2.jar file inside the maltparser directory to malt.jar. Ater that I typed the command (as instructed in the official site):

```
java -jar malt.jar
```

The distribution was successfully installed. Then I downloaded the pre trained model engmalt.linear-1.7.mco and extracted it to drive 'C' of my pc. After that I typed:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar malt.jar -c engmalt.linear-1.7.mco -i infile.conll -o outfile.conll -m parse
```

I received the following message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM. Too small initial heap.
I also tried by typing the commands:

java -Xmx1024m -jar malt.jar -c engmalt.linear-1.7 -i infile.conll -o outfile.conll -m parse
```

and

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar malt.jar -c engmalt.linear -i infile.conll -o outfile.conll -m parse
```

In both the cases I get the same message. Can anyone suggest what to do? Moreover I tried executing the following code:

```
import nltk

parser = nltk.parse.malt.MaltParser(working_dir = "C:/maltparser", mco =     "engmalt.linear-1.7")
txt = "This is a test sentence"
graph = parser.raw_parse(txt)
graph.tree().pprint()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\DURLOV\My Documents\PythonWorkspace\DomainSentimentLexicon\parser.py", line 5, in graph = parser.raw_parse(txt) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\malt.py", line 111, in raw_parse return self.parse(words, verbose) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\malt.py", line 98, in parse return self.tagged_parse(taggedwords, verbose) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\malt.py", line 150, in tagged_parse "code %d" % (' '.join(cmd), ret)) Exception: MaltParser parsing (java -jar C:\maltparser\malt.jar -w C:/maltparser -c engmalt.linear-1.7 -i C:\maltparser\malt_input.conllxaljvi -o C:\maltparser\malt_output.conll4bt_gl -m parse) failed with exit code 1
```

what should I do?